# Installing MSSql Server 2008 Driver for PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have installed Microsoft driver SQLSrv 3.0, installed it, gave the path to php extentions folder. Changed the Php.ini file to include the code
       extensions=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll

But when i tried to check whether the drivers loaded by the phpinfo method, The info page doesnot include Sqlsrv section.
I m using Wamp server and windows 7.. php 5.3.6

It means drivers are not loaded. What can be the possible error . Any body help

Answer (score 0):

SQLSRV 3.0 has the Microsoft Native Client 11 as a dependency. This is available for free from Microsoft. (It is also installed when you install SQL Server 2012.)

Try installing SQLSRV 3.0 using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer; that will probably address all of the dependencies for you.